# How to get Result of GwebSearchClient

Tags: c#, google-search-api

I am using GoogleSearchAPI to find out some information in that I have used below mentioned code

```
GwebSearchClient client = new GwebSearchClient("test");
IList<IWebResult> results = client.Search("vampire diaries", 20);
foreach (IWebResult result in results)
{
   Response.Write(String.Format("[{0}] {1} => {2} <br/><br/><br/>", result.Title, result.Content, result.Url));
}
```

but it will give me .com urls, Is it possible to find out result by filter I mean I need only .UK urls or .US urls.

How would I get this kind of details?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes you can add the filter like

```
 IEnumerable<IWebResult> result = client.Search(keyword.Name.Trim(), 20, "", "", "", "English","", "uk");
```